# Non-Union query column does not result as expected

Tags: sql, oracle

Here, I am getting all ids from different tables and storing it in the dataset using 'with' statement. What I need is that for all of these ids I wanted to pull a column named 'stat' from CO_C.

I am assuming that i might need to combine the result of the unionall and then do a left join with CO_C on id.

CO_C table looks like this:

```
id           Stat
FJERHT     Executed
HRFGER     Not Executed
JEREFH     other 
JFHZFH     Executed
```

Query

```
with dataset as(
SELECT DISTINCT
  NAME AS id,
  'DIM' as "Source"
FROM
  CO_D

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
  PRO_ID AS id,
  'CON' as "Source"
  stat as stat         -----> this gives me error query block has an incorrect number of result columns
FROM
  CO_C

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
  P_ID AS id,
  'STU' as "Source"
FROM
  CO_O

select * from dataset
PIVOT (
    COUNT(*)
    FOR "Source"
    IN (
'DIM' as "Avail",
'CON' as CON,
'STU' as STU)
```

Update i tried:

```
SELECT ID, stat
FROM CO_C
WHERE ID IN
(with dataset as(
    SELECT DISTINCT
      NAME AS id,
      'DIM' as "Source"
    FROM
      CO_D
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
      PRO_ID AS id,
      'CON' as "Source"
      stat as stat          
    FROM
      CO_C
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
      P_ID AS id,
      'STU' as "Source"
    FROM
      CO_O
    
    select * from dataset
    PIVOT (
        COUNT(*)
        FOR "Source"
        IN (
    'DIM' as "Avail",
    'CON' as CON,
    'STU' as STU)
```

Error: Missing select keyword

Comment: The select lists must match, i.e. same number of columns, and compatible data types. Add NULL to the shorter select lists as 3:rd column.

Comment: Why does your title say "non-union" when the query clearly involves UNION?

Comment: I meant that because I cannot include the column I wanted in a union query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, stat
FROM CO_C
WHERE ID IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
      NAME AS id,
      'DIM' as "Source"
    FROM
      CO_D
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
      PRO_ID AS id,
      'CON' as "Source"
      stat as stat          
    FROM
      CO_C
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT DISTINCT
      P_ID AS id,
      'STU' as "Source"
    FROM
      CO_O)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a UNION query, all of the queries that are being combined must deliver the same number of columns. In your case, the SELECT throwing the error has three columns where the previous SELECT returns only two. If this is what you want, you might want to consider delivering NULLs for the unused columns in your queries that only return two columns.

Comment: i am sorry, i fixed that actually i was retrieving only three column results but also i wanted stat column to be retrieved as well.

Comment: Got it (I think). Can you modify your question with the SQL as it looks now?

Comment: Thanks! You're still bringing back the wrong number of columns, though. This query brings back three columns in the SELECT statement (id, source, and stat) whereas your other SELECTS only bring back two:  SELECT DISTINCT
      PRO_ID AS id,
      'CON' as "Source"
      stat as stat